# Change value input field according to other fields

Tags: 7, forms, javascript, input-formats

I have 10 input fields when you create a product (= node). I have an input field amount, price & reduction and sell price. So when the field amount, price & reduction are filled in I want to automatically fill in the sell price field.

Is there a module for this or should I just write some javascript to do this?

I've seen the [Computed Field](https://drupal.org/project/computed_field) but I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: I think [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/182380/252070) is relevant to your question and may explain the down votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can adopt a method like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#a1').keyup(calculate);
    $('#a2').keyup(calculate);
});
function calculate(e)
{
    $('#a3').val($('#a1').val() * $('#a2').val());
}
```

using js

Comment: You should use Drupal behaviors.